# How can I change my name on Google Play Games?

Tags: google-plus, google-play-games

I opened up Google Play Games and clicked my way through it and it has changed my name to 'HighLemon4719'. Previously it was 'crazymaster' with my icon for Google+.

Every time I start a game on my phone it comes up as the name 'HighLemon4719'. How can I change it as I not like this name?

Answer (score 6):

1. Open up [Play Games](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.play.games) and click on your avatar in the header.
2. Click the Pencil icon in the top right hand corner of the app.
3. You should then be able to enter a new 'Gamer ID' to replace 'HighLemon4719'. You can also change the avatar image that is displayed too.
4. Click `Save`

Comment: No pencil there. Anything to change the name.